# How can I loop through HDF5 files and extract data I want into a .csv?

Tags: r, loops, hdf5, lidar

I am interested in extracting lidar data from HDF5 files.
Each HDF5 file has 8 beams (essentially 8 separate datasets), and I have 38 HDF5 files.
I have used the following code to extract the data of interest from one beam:

```
file_one = "D:/GEDI_Thesis_Data/L2A/56143-1/2432389212/processed_GEDI02_A_2019121080625_O02166_02_T05019_02_003_01_V002.h5"

tmp = h5ls(file_one)

beam = h5read(file_one, "/BEAM0000/beam")
lon = h5read(file_one, "/BEAM0000/lon_lowestmode")
lat = h5read(file_one, "/BEAM0000/lat_lowestmode")
sht_numb = h5read(file_one, "/BEAM0000/shot_number",
                  bit64conversion='bit64')
sht_numb = paste0(sht_numb)
qlty_fl = h5read(file_one, "/BEAM0000/quality_flag")
dgrd_fl = h5read(file_one, "/BEAM0000/degrade_flag")
delt_tm = h5read(file_one, "/BEAM0000/delta_time")
snstvty = h5read(file_one, "/BEAM0000/sensitivity")
slr_lvt = h5read(file_one, "/BEAM0000/solar_elevation")
elv_hgh = h5read(file_one, "/BEAM0000/elev_highestreturn")
elv_lws = h5read(file_one, "/BEAM0000/elev_lowestmode")
rh = h5read(file_one, "BEAM0000/rh")
rh = as.data.frame(t(rh))
colnames(rh) = paste0('rh', 0:100)

T05019_BEAM0000 = cbind(beam, lon, lat, sht_numb, dgrd_fl, qlty_fl, delt_tm, snstvty, slr_lvt, elv_hgh, elv_lws, rh)

write.csv(T05019_BEAM0000, paste0(sht_numb), "D:/GEDI_Thesis_Data/L2A_csvfiles/T05019_BEAM0000.csv")
```

Now I would very much like to avoid repeating this code over 300 times for all of the beams in every HDF5 file.
Is there a way to loop through each file and extract what I need in one table?

Working out of RStudio

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can write a function that includes most of the above code and then use lapply instead of a loop.

Comment: take a look at the rGEDI package